# Double ask for input if wrong input is given

Tags: c, list, case-sensitive

My functions:

```
//Check Character Case(Upper/Lower Case). If Upper Convert to Lower Case.
char checkLetterCase(char letter){
    if(letter >= 65 && letter <= 90){
        letter = tolower(letter);
        return letter;
    }
    else if(letter >= 97 && letter <= 122){
        return letter;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

//Add the Specified Letter by Creating a New Node in the Letter List defined
void addLetter(letterListT *letListHead, char letter){
    letterListT *newNode;
    newNode = (letterListT *)malloc(sizeof(letterListT));

    //Check Case(lowe/upper)
    letter = checkLetterCase(letter);  

    //This may only occur on user input
    while(letter == 0){
        printf("Guess a letter: ");
        scanf("%c", &letter);
        letter = checkLetterCase(letter);
    }

     newNode->letter = letter;

    newNode->nxt = letListHead->nxt;
    letListHead->nxt = newNode;
}
```

My call in main:

```
addLetter(unusedLetList, i=0);
```

and this is my outpun on run:

```
Guess a letter: 6
Guess a letter: Guess a letter: t
```

and my question is: why when i put a non character i get the "Guess a letter" message twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after pressing `<enter>`, there's an extra newline character that is not (yet) consumed by `scanf()`. Make a call to `getchar()` to get rid of that:

```
letter = checkLetterCase(letter);
if (letter == 0) getchar();
```

By the way, your `checkLetterCase()` function is broken on non-ASCII systems. Use this instead:

```
#include <ctype.h>

char checkLetterCase(char letter)
{
    return isalpha(letter) ? letter : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little suggest about avoiding nasty things with buffers, just don't use scanf.You could use it and clean the buffer, of you could use fgets.
I suppose that you could learn how to use it by reading the manual, but I'll make you an example:

```
while(letter == 0)
{
    char buffer[10];
    printf("Guess a letter: ");
    fgets(buffer,10,stdin);
    if(strlen(buffer)==2)
        letter = checkLetterCase(buffer[0]);
}
```

Comment: That was really helpful but may i ask why char buffer[] size is 10 when we at most want an input of 1(char)+1('\n')? just wondering.

Comment: It could have a minimum size of 4.Two for the first and second character, one for the '\n' character and one for the terminator.The second character is useful to see if the user has typed a too long string, in that case the input is wrong.